# Error: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, database, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

The error has come up on a number of different reports i have tried to run. Does anyone know why/what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT Event.Event_ID, Event.Event_Type, Avg (Rank.Time_InSeconds), Meeting.Meeting_ID
FROM Event, Rank, Meeting
WHERE Event.Event_ID = 7 AND Event.Event_ID = Rank.Event_ID AND Rank.Meeting_ID = Meeting.Meeting_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a blank between `AVG (Rank.Time_InSeconds)` ... try

```
SELECT Event.Event_ID, Event.Event_Type, Avg(Rank.Time_InSeconds), Meeting.Meeting_ID
FROM Event, Rank, Meeting
WHERE Event.Event_ID = 7 AND Event.Event_ID = Rank.Event_ID AND Rank.Meeting_ID = Meeting.Meeting_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `avg` aggregate, you need to also use `group by` clause :

```
SELECT e.Event_ID, e.Event_Type, m.Meeting_ID,
       Avg(r.Time_InSeconds)
FROM Event e 
       JOIN Rank r ON e.Event_ID = r.Event_ID
       JOIN Meeting m ON r.Meeting_ID = m.Meeting_ID
WHERE e.Event_ID = 7 
GROUP BY e.Event_ID, e.Event_Type, m.Meeting_ID
```

Also please notice the usage of the `join` syntax.  In general, I wouldn't recommend commas in the `from` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY clause is normally used along with five built-in, or "aggregate" functions. These functions perform special operations on an entire table or on a set, or group, of rows rather than on each row and then return one row of values for each group.